# xcode stay on second view controller when application open after long time

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have first view controller and second view controller. I will go from first view controller to second view controller. After that, I will go to other application or browse for some time. Then, when I come back, it always go back to first view controller as the new application open. How shall I just stay in particular view after I come back ?

Comment: Call this  when you come back to App : **[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];**

Comment: Show some code when you go to some page or browse from second view controller. You are doing something wrong in your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Read about  [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) , it's very useful in your case

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your app again start with the first view controller, after coming into active state?
I think app start from where it left.

Either you're doing something in the code to load the first view controller again, or
you can store the state and on coming into foreground can reset the previous state.